Equation numbering inside Definition, Example etc
I am writing a report within which I want to have definitions and examples.
In the main text of the report I have equations numbered according to their order and according to the chapter they belong to.
Hence, in chapter 2, I will have equations (2.1), (2.2) etc... while examples will be Examples 2.1, Example 2.2 as well.
For the equations appearing in the examples, I would like to identify them specifically so as not to follow the automatic numbering from the chapter but as sort of independent numbering for that example with equation labels of the form (Ex2.1.1) for the first equation of the Example 2.1 and (Ex2.1.2) for the 2nd equation of the example and so on.
I know that I can do it by using the \tag command, but I wanted to know if there was a possible automatic way of doing it.
The main problem is that if I need to insert an additional example somewhere, it is going to affect all the numbering I would have to do by hand when using \tag.

Please tell us which document class you employ.

You could use a second counter and swap \c@equation between the two.  Also swap \theequation at the same time.

@Mico It's a book

@JohnKormylo Could you please provide an example of how that would work?

When the example environment begins, save the current value of equation, set it to 0 and change the meaning of \theequation. At the end of the environment, restore the value of equation.
No need to restore \theequation, because it is redefined only locally.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newcounter{rememberequation}

\AddToHook{env/example/begin}{%
  \setcounter{rememberequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{Ex\theexample.\arabic{equation}}%
}
\AddToHook{env/example/end}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{rememberequation}}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

Some text with an equation
\begin{equation}
0+0=0
\end{equation}

\begin{example}
This is an example with two equations
\begin{equation}\label{test1}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
and the next follows
\begin{equation}
2+2=4
\end{equation}
Enough.
\end{example}

Now another equation
\begin{equation}\label{test2}
3+3=6
\end{equation}
We can refer to \eqref{test1} and \eqref{test2}.

\end{document}


